# How can I fixed these errors on youtube json api?

Tags: android

I'm working on youtube api wtih JSON . I have not error on code but
why do I see this errors on Log?

[image]

Comment: You have a variable that is null (`storage`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either you forgot to initialize `storage` variable or there is null in `storage` variable. Send me code so i can know well